# how to add an .mp4 to a button in uitableviewcell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm new to XCode and have built a UITableView in Storyboard. The first UITableViewCell has a button that, when pressed, should load an .mp4 full screen. I'm using the MediaPlayerFramework to make this happen.

My .mp4 file is in the project, and it appears in CopyBundleResources...but I am definitely missing a step because I get the following error when I select the button in IOS Simulator:

"*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'"

I also have this warning: "Dependency Analysis Warning: warning: no rule to process file '/Users/../my_mov1.mp4' of type file for architecture i386'

HERE is the code I have in the subclass for the TableViewController:

**RecipleTableViewController.h**

```
@interface RecipleTableViewController : UITableViewController {


}

-(IBAction)playvideo;

@end
```

**RecipleTableViewController.m**

```
#import "RecipleTableViewController.h"
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

@interface RecipleTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation RecipleTableViewController

-(IBAction)playvideo {


    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"my_mov" ofType:@"mp4"]];
    MPMoviePlayerViewController *playercontroller = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:playercontroller];

    playercontroller.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;

    [playercontroller.moviePlayer play];
}


- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

//- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
//{
#warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
 //   return 0;
//}

//- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
//{
  //  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
   // UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...

    //return cell;
//}

/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}
*/

/*
// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }   
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }   
}
*/

/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES;
}
*/

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a story board-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}

 */

@end
```

Any ideas what I'm (surely) missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you confirm that, the result of the expression > [NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"my_mov" ofType:@"mp4"] is not nil ?

Comment: It shouldn't be nil, it should be the .mp4 file...but I am not writing the expression correctly it seems...

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get the URL for `my_mov` while the actual file name seems to be `my_mov1`.

Comment: Good catch! + 1 for the eagle eyes.

Comment: Hi! I actually have six movie files in the app, from my_mov to my_mov5, and all of them display the Dependency Warning. The above was just an example of the five. Sorry for the confusion.